# chrome developer tools does not display?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm using Version 80.0.3987.116 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1304].  The Chrome Developer Tools simply do not appear for me no matter which way I try to access them:

- ctrl+shift+i
- f12
- ctrl+shift+j to open the last used panel
- ctrl+shift+c to open the elements panel
- right click on a web page and select inspect from the popup
- menu dots menu -> more tools ->
  developer tools

I've restarted my computer.  I've gone into settings -> advanced settings and restored all settings to their original defaults, then restarted chrome.  This disables all extensions, so even with all extensions disabled it still didn't display.  I've cleared the cache.

It was all working last Friday, but not when I tried Monday.

Has anyone seen this or have any other troubleshooting ideas?  The only other thing I can think of is uninstall with something like Revo Uninstaller to scrape the registry and filesystem, then in my profile zip up then delete %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google and %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Google.  That seems extreme if there's an easier way.

Anyone seen anything similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I feel stupid figuring this out so quickly after posting the question.  But if anyone else finds this, here's what worked for me.

1. ctrl+t to open a new tab
2. enter chrome://flags/ in the address bar
3. click reset all to default
4. let chrome restart

I'm not sure which flag was set that caused this.  When I searched for devtools, there were three available settings, and they were all set to either disabled or default.  And that's what they were after I did a reset all too.  So whatever broke it was some other setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Issue on networks tab, the following worked for me(not sure if will work for other tabs):

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]